# Help with a jQuery scrollable plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, scroll, slider, scrollable

I have come across an interesting code example that allows me to make DIV elements scrollable using jQuery (UI), which can be found here: http://www.simonbattersby.com/demos/vertical_scrollbar_demo.htm

I have subsequently turned it into a plugin to make it easier to use and more reusable. It's working 99% but there is one small bug - for some reason when I CLICK the scrollbar it doesn't scroll the DIV element.

If I use the mousewheel it works fine, but for some reason the click and drag doesn't work.

The code I am working on is here: http://jsfiddle.net/mitchmalone/XRnxL/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out.

```
slide: function (event, ui) {
    var topValue = -((100 - ui.value) * difference / 100);
    $(this).parents(".slider-wrap").prev(".scroll-pane").find('.scroll-content').css({
        top: topValue
    });
},
change: function (event, ui) {
    var topValue = -((100 - ui.value) * difference / 100);
    $(this).parents(".slider-wrap").prev(".scroll-pane").find('.scroll-content').css({
        top: topValue
    });
}
```

This issue was that `$(this)` is referencing `div.slider-vertical`  calling `find` directly on the `.scroll-content` produced no results as `.scroll-content` is not a child of `div.slider-vertical`.  To fix we need to traverse back up the dom and find the prev `.scroll-pane` and then find our `.scroll-content` and adjust the css value.

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/XRnxL/4/).

Comment: Thanks very much Mark. If I could vote this up more than once I definitely would. Made a small update of my own and removed the change event since it's not needed. Updaeted fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mitchmalone/XRnxL/

Comment: No problem Mitch, glad I was able to help!